# exclude file from rm in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile that has a clean PHONY like this:

```
.PHONY: clean

clean: clean_target 

# Remove files created by the build process.
clean_target:
    rm -rf *.mcs *.bit *.bin *.twr *.pwr *.tsi *.twx *.ncd *.pcf *.ngd *.ngc
```

I want to exclude a file named "FIFO.ngc" from being removed. How can I do that?

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using GNU make you could do it like this:

```
clean_target:
        rm -rf *.mcs *.bit *.bin *.twr *.pwr *.tsi *.twx *.ncd *.pcf *.ngd \
            $(filter-out FIFO.ngc,$(wildcard *.ngc))
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit lengthy, but you could remove the '*.ngc' from the list and add another line:

```
find . -type f -name '*.ngc' -not -name 'FIFO.ngc' -delete
```